# Laravel retornar valor de una consulta limpio

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy ejecutando una consulta sql y guardo el dato en una variable para luego guardarla en una tabla

esta es la consulta

```
$int_nom = DB::table('detalle_colecciones')
        ->join('colecciones','colecciones.col_id','=','detalle_colecciones.col_id')
        ->join('cartas','cartas.card_id','=','detalle_colecciones.card_id')
        ->select('cartas.card_nom')
        ->where('detalle_colecciones.dc_id','=',$dc_id)->get();
```

funciona casi bien, pero me guarda en la base de datos el dato agregado de caracteres

```
[{"card_nom":"Perro"}]
```

¿Como puedo quitar los parentesis y las comillas para guardar solo Perro?

Comment: Eso  es lo que quiero lograr

Comment: debe devolver solo un registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Estás obteniendo una colección al utilizar `get()`
- Entonces podemos cambiar `get()` por `first` para indicar que solo nos regrese el primer elemento coincidente
- Una vez hecho dicho cambio podemos agregar el uso de pluck para solo devolver el valor de la clave especificada que en este caso sería `card_nom` el cual será el valor que le pasaremos como argumento a dicho método
- Con esto puedes remover el uso del método `select` ya que no será necesario

Entonces tu consulta puede quedar así:

```
$int_nom = DB::table('detalle_colecciones')
        ->join('colecciones','colecciones.col_id','=','detalle_colecciones.col_id')
        ->join('cartas','cartas.card_id','=','detalle_colecciones.card_id')
        ->where('detalle_colecciones.dc_id','=',$dc_id)
        ->pluck('card_nom')
        ->first();
```

Por cierto y como consejo final *deberías trabajar con los modelos para aprovechar el potencial de Eloquent*

Aquí puedes leer más al respecto https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: Si lo que se quiere obtener es solo el valor de una columna del primer resultado, lo correcto es utilizar [`->value('card_nom')`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results), sin `pluck()` y sin `first()`. Al hacer `pluck()` estás trayendo todos los registros de la DB para después seleccionar el primero de la colección. Por otro lado, ojo porque el link a la documentación de `pluck()` es incorrecto, ese `pluck()` es el de `Collections`, no el de `Query Builder`.

Comment: @azeos, vaya tienes razón, sería bueno una respuesta amigo

Comment: Si querés editá la tuya, está lo suficientemente bien planteada. Pero si preferís que responda, no hay ningún problema.

Answer (score 3):

Te lo está guardando de esa forma porque está transformando los resultados obtenidos en JSON.

Tenés 2 problemas:

1. Al utilizar [`get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results) traés múltiples resultados de la DB y vos necesitás solo uno.
2. Estás obteniendo el *nombre* del campo y su *valor*, vos necesitás solo el valor.

Para solucionar ambos problemas, lo correcto es utilizar [`value()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results).

```
$int_nom = DB::table('detalle_colecciones')
        ->join('colecciones', 'colecciones.col_id', '=', 'detalle_colecciones.col_id')
        ->join('cartas', 'cartas.card_id', '=', 'detalle_colecciones.card_id')
        ->where('detalle_colecciones.dc_id', $dc_id)
        ->value('card_nom');
```

`value()` lo que hace es correr un `first()` (en vez de `get()`) con lo cual trae un solo resultado y por último devuelve el valor del campo sin el nombre del mismo.

Podes ver su funcionamiento [acá](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L497).

Answer (score 0):

Si usas `get()` en la consulta, te traera un array de datos posibles, si solo es uno puede usar `firts();` para atraer solo un objecto

```
$data = DB::table('detalle_colecciones')
    ->join('colecciones','colecciones.col_id','=','detalle_colecciones.col_id')
    ->join('cartas','cartas.card_id','=','detalle_colecciones.card_id')
    ->select('cartas.card_nom')
    ->where('detalle_colecciones.dc_id','=',$dc_id)->first();
```

Ya solo es sacar el dato de objecto `MITABLA::create(['columanaTal' => $data->card_nom])`